# Adding a dijit.Editor after page load

Tags: jquery, editor, load, dojo

Hey Experts, please help me out with a dijit.Editor doubt.

I want to add a dijit.Editor dynamically to my Page using jQuery.

my code is:
`jQuery(#foo).before("<textarea width='500px' name='page_text2[]' dojoType='dijit.Editor' ></textarea>");`

The textarea gets created, but dijit.Editor does not show.

It seems dojo only parses elements onLoad.

Is it possible to insert dojo elements on the fly, after the page is loaded completely?

i'm missing something?

thanks.

Comment: it seems it needs to use dojo.parser.parse - but it is not working :(

Comment: solved (ALONE) .. hehe 

used dojo.parser.parse to the div and not to the widget. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
                 var editor= new dijit.Editor({
                    name : 'editor_name',
                 }, dojo.byId('id_editor'));
```